# Who are these toy elves?

Tags: character-identification

I have no idea where my children got these toy elves (they don't remember, my wife doesn't too).
They are made of plastic and are 4 cm (1.5 inches) tall.
There are NO markings, logos, symbols, copyright notice, etc.

### Who are they?

Are they just "random" elves? or elves from a specific franchise?

Note that I call them "elves" because of their pointy ears, but I'm not sure they're elves, they may be goblins or other magic folks; and those protruding things on their forehead confuse me (antennas? horns? part of their hair?)

I tries various queries on Google Images, and I browsed 200+ items on IMDB with the keyword "elf", finding nothing.
I also tried to take a picture of them and use the "similar images" feature of Google Images, with both characters, only one, only the face, etc, but it only identifies them as "toy", "figurine" or "face", which doesn't help.

[image: Two toy elves, male and female]
<sub>Click for full resolution</sub>

Comment: Took it 5 minutes here. The power of the Internet!

Comment: Almost certainly from a Happy Meal or equivalent, I'd imagine.

Comment: Neither of you remember how your children got them?  Let's hope that they aren't part of some changeling plot!  You didn't upset any Gypsy women, did you?

Comment: Before I read the answer: Not sure why you thought they were "elves." Definitely look like aliens to me.

Comment: @can-ned_food and DanielRoseman: definitely a McDonald-Gypsy conspiracy. With aliens. The plot thickens!

Comment: @jpmc: as I said in the comment below, I'm amazed myself. In hindsight, of course. ("Tombs are full of hindsight wisdom", the Italian proverb goes). Maybe I had racial prejudices on green aliens - e.g. I expected them to be bald?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

These are characters from the movie *[Planet 51](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0762125/)*, Lem and Neera, voiced by Justin Long and Jessica Biel, respectively.

[image: Lem] [image: Neera]

Comment: Great, thank you! Shame on me, why did I think about elves and didn't think about the more obvious ALIENS? I focused on the ears instead of the antennas... Luckily the question is still in topic, since this is the "Fantasy and SCIENCE FICTION" stack exchange :) :) :)